# Nginx -> rewrite ordering or nesting

Tags: nginx, http, regex

I'm working on a new top-level domain, and redirect visitors of the new domain to the old one, except for my own work on the staging server:

I have a rule that rewrites the host if you don't hit the staging server, which works like a bomb.

```
if ($host != 'staging.xxx.com') {
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://xxx.co.za/$1 permanent;
}
```

the problem is that some callback from another site we are using is hitting `xxx.com/s/callback`. At the moment that is redirecting to the `.co.za` site, but I really want it to redirect to the staging server.

I have added the following ontop of the previous bit of code:

```
location ~ /s/ {
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://staging.xxx.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to catch the callback, i.e. if I visit `xxx.com/s/callback` it still redirects to `.co.za`.

Can anyone describe how to nest those location and if statements, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your doing it right, and are most likely seeing cache problems while your working on it...

Change "permanent" to "redirect" for now, and also add a line like:
expires epoch;

while your testing to stop the browser from caching

Best,

-Eric

Comment: thanks, i think that's how i solved the issue but it's now a while ago.